# Listing all movies of a specific cinema - Foreign Key Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I have a question regarding the models and foreignkeys.

I have two models: Cinema and Movie.
One Cinema can have multiple movies, so I placed the foreign key of cinema in the Movie model.

```
class Cinema(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    posting_cinema = models.ForeignKey('cinemas.Cinema', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Now I want to list all the movies of a specific Cinema.
How can I do it?

The idea is the following:
The user clicks on a cinema, it opens a page with the cinema details and a button "see movies". If the user clicks this button, a new page opens and I want to have listed there the movies of that specific cinema.

I tried to figured out some solutions but sadly I am stuck. I was thinking about Movie.objects.filter(#something) but I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given `Cinema` you can use:

```
some_cinema.movie_set.all()
```

Or you can give the `ForeignKey` a more sensical name to query in reverse:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    posting_cinema = models.ForeignKey(
        'cinemas.Cinema',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        # here we give the reverse relation a name
        related_name='movies'
    )
```

then you can query this with:

```
some_cinema.movies.all()
```

An alternative is to filter based on the `ForeignKey`, for example:

```
Movie.objects.filter(posting_cinema=some_cinema)
```

or if you have the primary key of the cinema:

```
Movie.objects.filter(posting_cinema__pk=some_cinema_pk)
```

(this can for example save a fetch of the `Cinema` object, if you never really need the `Cinema` itself).

Comment: - Where should I write "some_cinema.movie_set.all()", In my Cinema model or my Movie view?
- What does "some_cinema" refer to? Shouldn't I define it somewhere?
Thank you

Comment: FBSO: at the place where you need the movies. `some_cinema` is the cinema from which you want the movies. For example in a view where you want to list the movies, you might want to fetch the related movies there.

Comment: Ok! I created in my Movie view a function:
def movies_of_cinema():
         some_cinema.movie_set.all()
         #Do something which will then be used to build the html template
I guess I have to place "some_cinema.movie_set.all()" there. However I do not get 1) How does it understand from which cinema I want all the movies. How does it get that it is from cinema X and not cinema Y if there is not a cinema id?
2) "some_cinema" is naturally an unresolved reference. So I am missing a point.
I am sorry to bother you but I want to understand better this concept.

Comment: @FBSO: you encode the id of the `Cinema` in the URL, and if you want to render it, you need to define a view function, and define a URL (here one that takes a parameter), see for example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial04/

Comment: I tried following the guide without result. I do not have the cinema_id encoded in my URL. Instead I have something like that: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cinemas/movies/allmoviesofcinema`
In the `views` of `movie` I wrote:
`def allmoviesofcinema(request):
    movies = Movie.objects.filter(posting_cinema=3)
    return render(request, "movies/allmoviesofcinema.html",  {"movies": movies})`
posting_cinema=3 works, and it allow me to see the movies of cinema with id 3. But I want it dinamic, not static. I tried cinema_id but does not work.

Comment: But here you need an `id` in the URL, how else will you *pass* the cinema. If it is posted as POST parameter (for a form), you can obtain it through `request.POST`.